# TFS support (plugin, external tool, etc) from within MonoDevelop?

Tags: tfs, macos, monodevelop

Is there an easy way to integrate TFS for version control into [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)?  I have a new MacBook Pro and an trying to determine which things I can do with Mac native apps and which I will need to run using [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/).

I downloaded the [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=af1f5168-c0f7-47c6-be7a-2a83a6c02e57&displaylang=en) command-line client, and was able to create a workspace, map a working folder and get the latest code.  However, it would be nice to perform a get latest from inside MonoDevelop.  In the Options there are External Tools I can try and setup, but I thought someone might have already done this.  Has anybody done this?

Also, I see the the [opentf](http://code.google.com/p/opentf/) project lists an *alpha-quality MonoDevelop addin* in the Feb 4, 2008 [Release Notes](http://code.google.com/p/opentf/wiki/ReleaseNotes), but that is two years ago.  Has anybody used this?

Comment: As you said, OpenTF supports MonoDevelop and it makes a good impression on this screenshot: http://www.flickr.com/photos/11527903@N04/2231467443/in/set-72157601529234621/

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [Svn Bridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/). In order to use it you will need to install it on the TFS server itself. It will then allow your TFS server to communicate via SVN protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I retry to post an answer (sorry for my english i'm french). I has the same problem than you, i make some software for WP7 from visual studio and i use TFS in my compagny and want to make iphone applications with monotouch.
I Try openTF but i need direct integration in monodevelop, i find nothing in the internet and i decide to make my addin.
I release a test version (free of course) than you can try, it's integrate directly in monodevelop with TFS, and work for me on my mac.
You can see my blog at [teamaddins.com](http://www.teamaddins.com/blog) i think it's can help.

Bruno

Answer (score 1):

The least-bad solution I've come up with for Xamarin + TFS is to set up TFS through a Windows machine as normal, mount the TFS workspace as a SMB fileshare on the Mac, and manage checkouts manually in Visual Studio.

It's klugey, but there doesn't seem to be any reliable TFS tooling available for Mac.